# Is it possible to center text inside of <Icon /> component react-native-vector-icons

Tags: javascript, react-native

my simple question is: is it possible to center the text inside of Icon component, I tried with passing text like a child but it is not working? any other solution? I know that possible solution is with `position: 'absolute'` but is there any other way?

```
<View>
    <Icon
        color="blue"
        name="bookmark"
        size={scale(36)}
    />
    <Text style={[style.textBasic]}>text</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the simplest solution is with absolute:

```
<View style={{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
}}>
    <Icon
        color="blue"
        name="bookmark"
        size={scale(36)}
    />
    <Text style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>text</Text>
</View>
```